Prove that a necessary and sufficient condition $RQ(X):=\lambda_{max}$, where $\vert\vert x \vert \vert =1 $, is that $Ax=\lambda_{max}x$
I am trying to prove this question my current attempt is as follows.
NB $RQ(X):=\langle Ax,x \rangle$, with $A$ an adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ on $n$ and $m$ vertices.
($\Leftarrow$) $Ax=\lambda_{max} x \implies x^\intercal Ax = x^\intercal \lambda_{max} x \implies <Ax,x> = \lambda _{max} x^\intercal x \implies RQ(x)= \lambda_{max}   $
Now for the converse (this is the part where I am stuck),
Since $A$ is hermitian it can be written as $A=B^\intercal D B$, where $D_{ii}=\lambda_i$ is a diagonal matrix and $B$ and orthonormal matrix.
Then $RQ(x)=x^\intercal B^\intercal D B x = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i y_i^2 $ where $y_i$ is an entry of $Bx$.
Can any body shed light on how to proceed please ?
Thanks a lot :D

$D$ is not just any diagonal matrix! You should know what its entries are.
